# Optimal bounds for $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be unbounded and continuous everywhere.

Define $\mathcal{B}(x,\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Define $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}(x)=\sup\{\delta>0\:|\: f(\mathcal{B}(x,\delta))\subseteq\mathcal{B}(f(x),\epsilon))\}$

In other words, $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}(x)$ is the radius of the biggest open interval around $x$ that is mapped to an $\epsilon$-interval around $f(x)$.

For example, if $f(x)=1/x$, then $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}(x)=\frac{\epsilon|x|^2}{1+\epsilon|x|}$.

**Question:** Which functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}$ for some function $f$ and some $\epsilon>0$?

Of course, $g$ must take positive values everywhere. I also suspect that $g$ must be continuous, but I haven't proven this yet.

Comment: I don't understand what the question asks. You define "$\Delta_{f,\epsilon}(x)$ is the radius of the biggest open interval around $x$ that is mapped to an $\epsilon$-interval around $f(x)$." So $\Delta$ is a function. And the question is, Which functions "$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}$ for some function $f$ and some $\epsilon>0$?" But what does it mean for "a function *to be*  $\Delta_{f,\epsilon}$ "? The form of this question is, "What functions $g$ can be function $f$? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @AdamRubinson My reading is, "For which functions $g$ does there exist a continuous, unbounded $f$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $g = \Delta_{f, \varepsilon}$?"

Comment: A couple of observations: Because $f$ is unbounded, $g$ must be locally bounded everywhere (but need not be bounded). Because $f$ is locally uniformly continuous, $g$ must be bounded away from $0$ everywhere.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes your reading of the question is correct.

Comment: FWIW, $\Delta_{f,\varepsilon}$ need not be continuous.

Comment: To see why it doesn't need to be continuous, consider $f(x) = x^3 - 3x$, which has turning points $(-1, 4)$ and $(1,-2)$. If $\epsilon > 6, \Delta_{f,\epsilon}$ will jump in size $x = -1$ and $x = 1$.